# Intersection/union of measurable and nonmeasurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given a (Lebesgue) measurable set $A$ and a nonmeasurable set $B$, when is $A \cap B$ measurable? Nonmeasurable?

I think I know a case where the intersection turns out to be nonmeasurable (it involves the Cantor-Lebesgue function). I assume there are trivial cases (e.g. intersecting two disjoint sets), but I'm curious about more general results.

Also, what about the union of measurable and nonmeasurable sets?

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate; I looked around MSE for a bit so to my knowledge it is not.

Comment: My apologies, that's a typo.

Comment: I don't think you can find any nice general criteria... But for instance if $A$ has measure zero, then $A\cap B$ is measurable (every set with zero measure is measurable).